# How can I update python2.7.3 to python2.7.6 in Ubuntu12.0.4 LTS

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

Title is just the contents.
I'm using ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS and the default python binary has version 2.7.3.
But I hope to update it to 2.7.6 without errors (usually dependency)
I hope to have python2.7.6 when I enter "python" in the shell..

I tried 'pyenv' and it succeeded that job. But I cannot use module I just installed by using 'apt-get' or 'pip'.

Is there any guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since many systems depend on a certain version of python, you are best served by using [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) or even better [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

There is a nice article about this [here](http://www.jontourage.com/2011/02/09/virtualenv-pip-basics/).